# How to investigate if a workmanager is being used or not?

Tags: weblogic, workmanagers

We have like 20 WorkManagers and right now our project is in cleaning phase. I am assigned a task to list down all the workmanagers which are being used and which are not. I can see list of created workmanagers on WebLogic Console but how can i figure out if some work manager is handling some requests or ont?

- Is there any history graph?
- Is there any log?
- Anything which tells that which workmanager process which request?

Weblogic 10.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the admin console and see if all 20 Work Managers are serving requests.

Under

Deployments -> Your Application name -> Configuration -> Workload tab.